# Remove tv plaform on metal guides from old tv armoire

Tags: removal, self-assembly-furniture, guide

I have an armoire originally used to hold an old style TV.  I want to remove a platform that was to hold the TV.

The platform is wood and on metal, ball bearing, guides so that the tv could be pulled out and rotated.  I can't find any release hinges/levers, and there are no exposed screws.  The guides are not unlike drawer guides  so  I assume there must be some way to release the guides.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pictures always help.  Please provide some.

Comment: You will need to look closer there will normally be 2 screws on each side to hold the rails in place, don’t forget to look on the outside for plugged holes that could be concealing the screws.

Comment: I have added 3 pictures.  As you can see, there is not much room between the platform and the shelf it is mounted to.  Let me know if you need more information.  Again, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no release tabs on the slides edges(that are usually pressed to separate the two parts than you may have to remove the wood shelf that is attached to the slides.

Extend the shelf out fully and look underneath where it is attached to the slides. Look in the center of the slide track for Philip head screws going into the wood.

Also while the shelf is extended, look at the lower slide that attaches to the armoire shelf. Look for screws along the center of the track.

Sometimes the release tabs are not obvious and don't seem like tabs at all. They are usually located at the back of the top (extended/shelf) slide or the front of the lower slide. Usually along the edge on both.

Also look below the compartment where the TV is located. The lower slide may have been bolted through the Armoires' shelf (not likely, but possible).

Comment: Solved.  Thank you for all your help and suggestions.  When the  shelf is fully extended, there are 4 screws holding the guide to the shelf.  My mistake was thinking there were also screws on the front of the shelf.  But, after removing the 4 screws on the back, the shelf lifted easily.

Comment: @JessicaPohl - If ojait's answer answered your question then use the check mark link to choose it as correct please. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  and take the tour so you know how this site works. https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour